# SQL Server : get the node values from xml, but node names are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a weird question. Is it possible to get the `attval` node value filtered by `attrno` node from the XML shown below?

Example: I need to get the `attval` value where `attrno` is 12 and 2:

```
<attributes>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>2</attrno>
        <attval>NA</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>11</attrno>
        <attval>0123456</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>12</attrno>
        <attval>2210</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>10</attrno>
        <attval>0.049833</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>11</attrno>
        <attval>EA</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>12</attrno>
        <attval>EUR</attval>
    </attribute>
</attributes>
```

This is the T-SQL query I am trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO @temp (id, skid, Attval)
    SELECT      
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        col.value('(../../tcid/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'),
        col.value('(attval/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)')
    FROM
        @DataRecXML.nodes('/rec/tcids/tcid_rec/attributes/attribute') AS tb(col)
    WHERE 
        col.value('(attrno/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') = 2
        OR col.value('(attrno/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') = 12
        AND col.value ('(attval/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') <> 'EUR'
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: What is your DBMS? Tag the question accordingly, XML tools are product specific.

Comment: Which database system you are using? How did you put the data to the database? Is it just a text value in a column or using pl(?)sql command variable? Have you ever tried some query to test?

Comment: I am using MSSQL, I will edit the post and paste the sql query which i am trying to use

Comment: What is wrong with your query? It looks like it should return what you want.

Comment: Yes, but i still believe there is a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following solution.

The filters are applied in the XPath predicates. It makes code more compact and performant.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @DataRecXML XML =
N'<attributes>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>2</attrno>
        <attval>NA</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>11</attrno>
        <attval>0123456</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>12</attrno>
        <attval>2210</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>10</attrno>
        <attval>0.049833</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>11</attrno>
        <attval>EA</attval>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attrno>12</attrno>
        <attval>EUR</attval>
    </attribute>
</attributes>';

 SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        attrno = col.value('(attrno/text())[1]', 'INT'),
        attval = col.value('(attval/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)')
FROM @DataRecXML.nodes('/attributes/attribute[(attrno/text())[1]=("2","12") 
    and (attval/text())[1] ne "EUR"]') AS tb(col);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | attrno | attval |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      2 | NA     |
|  2 |     12 | 2210   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: OP query is using a bit different logic `attrno = 2 OR (attrno = 12  AND attval <> 'EUR')` .

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. This is a sample modelling the requested behaviour. What is wrong with the output?

```
select id, 
   a.n.value('attrno[1]', 'int') attrno,
   a.n.value('attval[1]', 'varchar(20)') attval
from  -- your table here
   ( select 1 id, cast(
'<attributes>
          <attribute>
            <attrno>2</attrno>
            <attval>NA</attval>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <attrno>11</attrno>
            <attval>0123456</attval>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <attrno>12</attrno>
            <attval>2210</attval>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <attrno>10</attrno>
            <attval>0.049833</attval>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <attrno>11</attrno>
            <attval>EA</attval>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <attrno>12</attrno>
            <attval>EUR</attval>
          </attribute>
        </attributes>' 
          as xml) xcol 
) tbl
cross apply xcol.nodes('attributes/attribute') a(n)
where a.n.value('attrno[1]', 'int') = 2 
     or a.n.value('attrno[1]', 'int') = 12 and a.n.value('attval[1]', 'varchar(20)') <> 'EUR'
```

Output

```
id  attrno  attval
1   2   NA
1   12  2210
```

Comment: Thank you @Serg, I thought there is an another way to do it, and my solution looked a bit weird, I learned again  something new :)

Answer (score -2):

A slightly different syntax of @YitzhakKhabinsky's excellent answer. Hard to say which is faster, you may need to test

```sql
 SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        attrno = col.value('(attrno/text())[1]', 'INT'),
        attval = col.value('(attval/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)')
FROM @DataRecXML.nodes('
  /attributes/attribute
    [attrno/text() = ("2", "12")] 
    [not(attval/text() = "EUR")]') AS tb(col);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4b1469826ddb3261ad78555a1b48a7c)